# A question about projection

Tags: linear-algebra

In a linear transformation of projections:

If you want to find a basis for the space "onto" and "along" which $T$ projects, is it $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ respectively?

Comment: A projection $T$ projects onto $R(T)$ along $N(T)$, yes.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is a (not necessarily orthogonal) projection, i.e., a linear operator such that $T^2 = T$, then $T$ does indeed project onto $R(T)$ along $N(T)$.